# PiGPIO inconsistent when using servo

Tags: gpio, pigpio, servo

so I will do the following command once and it will work and then the same sequence of commands never works again. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

The commands are to first arm some ESCs then actually activate them

```
pigs s 4 2000
pigs s 4 1000
pigs s 4 1200
```

Comment: Why would you want to “arm” them the second time around?

Comment: You need to find the details for your ESC.  Does it give arming instructions?  I suggest trying some delays, e.g. try `pigs s 4 2000 mils 1000 s 4 1000 mils 1000 s 4 1200`